# How to make a button for a color

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, android-canvas

I'm creating a game app for android that when a green circle or (Button) is clicked then you get rewarded and if a red circle or (Button) then you lose the game. My problem is creating these buttons for the circles. I already have made the generator for the circles with the help of someone else on here and I have attempted to create the buttons. Here is all the code I have so far:

```
public class Main extends Activity 
{
    DrawingView v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        v = new DrawingView(this);
        setContentView(v);

        Button redCircle = (Button) findViewById(Color.RED);

        redCircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent s = new Intent(Main.this, ifRed());

                startActivity(s);
            }

            private Class<?> ifRed() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String str = "You clicked on a red circle. You Loose!";

                System.out.print(str);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the circle generator below:

```
public class DrawingView extends View 
{
    public DrawingView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 380);
        }
    };

    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() 
    {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() 
    {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        canvas.drawCircle(random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-radius/2) + radius/2f, random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-radius/2) + radius/2f, radius, paint);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Is there any meaningful difference between this question and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335639/how-to-make-a-variable-button-that-you-can-click) you asked an hour ago?

Comment: worded differently so people can understand it better that way it can be answered

Comment: I think the preferred way to deal with that is to edit the original instead of posting what amounts to a duplicate. As I said on the other, I think your problem isn't with the wording entirely, it's the wording matched with the code. Are the circles supposed to be the buttons; are you generating images the buttons should use? What xml relates to `Button redCircle = (Button) findViewById(Color.RED);`; what does or do you want/think this achieves? What is the current state; does it run, crash, grant wishes?

Comment: yes the circles are supposed to be displayed and no that line of code crashes the program because Color.RED is an int and the id is found in xml but i cant set the button id in the xml because it is initialized in drawing view class in java

Comment: also the view is set to DrawingView

Comment: This can't be right: `Button redCircle = (Button) findViewById(Color.RED);
` Post your layout file, check what the id is of your button, use that in your code.